# Integrating Apache deltaSpike scheduler Module

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cdi, deltaspike

While i was creating a scheduler i found it impossible to use the CDI injection in it, after some research i found an interesting solution by using the scheduler module of the API deltaSpike.

I followed all the steps described in the official documentation so i added the following depencies on my pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.distribution</groupId>
            <artifactId>distributions-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-weld</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-scheduler-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-scheduler-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But every time a start my jboss Server this Exception is thrown

```
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:343)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:340)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:162)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:322)
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:81)
at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getAllProperties(ConfigResolver.java:383)
at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.extension.ExcludeExtension.init(ExcludeExtension.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
... 14 more
 "}}}}
```

Regarding the exception i missed something concerning the configuration of deltaspike , but i did not find anything in stackoverflow or in any other website, please Help

Comment: What version of deltaspike are you using and what container are you deploying to?

Comment: the version of deltaSpike i was using is 1.6.0 , and i'm deploying in Jboss 7.1 A.S

Answer (score -2):

Well , the problem is solved , i was interested by deltaSpike , because i was trying to figure out how to use Quartz , in a CDI context.

After some research , i found that EJB Timer is perfect for me because we are using JBOSS A.S whitch is actually an ejb Container.

Comment: That's not really a solution :-( since others may have the same problem with DeltaSpike and need it for something other than a timer.